# SearchDisplayController table not showing in custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have an `UIViewController`. Inside the view controller there is a custom `UIView` class object added as subview. Now, inside the custom `UIView` class, I have a search display controller. When I do this

```
SearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:SearchBar contentsController:self]
```

it is giving warning as self is `UIView` object, not `UIViewcontroller` object, so search result is not showing.

I want to show search result from the `UIView` only.

How can I do that? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? What's your goal? It's not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a UIViewController with the custom view you need and then add this controller's view to your view. Something like:

`[self.view addSubview:[[[UIViewController alloc] init] view]];`

Remember that UISearchDisplayController have a UITableView and that needs a UIViewController as a delegate. Just a UIView will not do.

Comment: That's not correct!! You should not force to load of a view that belongs to a view controller. The loading is async.

Comment: It is ok as long as (on ARC) you keep this UIViewController as an iVar and you manage it's memory (e.g. make it nil and make sure it is deallocated when it should). Don't you agree?

Comment: Thnx for ur comments...what i have done is that in the view in which the search display controller is there,i have given the content controller of the search as the rootviewcontroller and it is working fine...:-)